# Nested type in Elasticsearch: "object mapping can't be changed from nested to non-nested" when indexing a document

Tags: elasticsearch, nested, mapping

I try to index some nested documents into an Elasticsearch (v2.3.1) mapping which looks as follows [(based on this example from the documentation)](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-mapping.html):

```
PUT /my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "blogpost": {
      "properties": {
        "title": { "type": "string" },
        "comments": {
          "type": "nested", 
          "properties": {
            "name":    { "type": "string"  },
            "comment": { "type": "string"  }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, I do not understand what my JSON documents have to look like in order to fit into that mapping. I tried with

```
PUT /my_index/some_type/1
{
  "title": "some_title",
  "comments": {
    "name": "some_name",
    "comment": "some_comment"
  }
}
```

as well as with

```
PUT /my_index_some_type/1
{
  "title": "some_title",
  "comments": [
      {
        "name": "some_name",
        "comment": "some_comment"
      }
  ]
}
```

which both result in

```
{

    "error": 

{

    "root_cause": 

[

            {
                "type": "remote_transport_exception",
                "reason": "[Caiman][172.18.0.4:9300][indices:data/write/index[p]]"
            }
        ],
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "object mapping [comments] can't be changed from nested to non-nested"
    },
    "status": ​400

}
```

Which is the correct format to index nested documents? Any working examples are much appreciated, most examples here at SO or on other pages concentrate on nested queries rather than how the documents have been indexed before.

Comment: Are you using the `blogpost` mapping type in your URL or not? It's not clear from your question (i.e. `some_type` vs `blogpost`). It seems you're really creating a document of type `some_type` and `comments` will default to a normal object, which is not allowed since you already have a nested object called `comments` in the `blogpost` mapping type.

Comment: Ahh no, seriously... that's what happens when you copy and paste too much from different sources. If you want to add this as an answer, I'll be happy to accept it so that we have one more complete example around.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It seems you're really creating a document of type `some_type` and `comments` will default to a normal `object` (i.e. not `nested`), which is not allowed since you already have a nested object called `comments` in the `blogpost` mapping type in the same index.

Try this instead and it should work:

```
PUT /my_index/blogpost/1
{
  "title": "some_title",
  "comments": {
    "name": "some_name",
    "comment": "some_comment"
  }
}
```

Comment: How is this an answer? It's exactly as the same as the example that doesn't work (except for the change of the type). I have this problem, I am using the correct type, and I keep getting the same error.

Comment: @Gullbyrd look at the type name more carefully (hint: `blogpost` instead of `some_type`) ;-) I suggest you create a new question referencing this one but explaining your context and details and we'll be able to figure it out.

Comment: @Val while it works if I remove the type, how do i still ensure that the document type is what i want it to be when i create it. I'm migrating from 2.4 to 7.6

Comment: @Val (answering my own question) I just figured it out. As per the documentation, mapping-types are removed.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.6/removal-of-types.html
We need to either use an explicit field or use a different index for each mapping type.